# Using different payment methods for different projects in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In AWS,I want:

- All resources for project 1 to be charged onto payment method 1
- All resources for project 2 to be charged onto payment method 2

How can I do this?

I have looked at the AWS organisations feature, but this seems to help consolidate billing across different AWS accounts, which is the opposite of what I want to do.

The only other option I can find is to create a new AWS account with a different AWS email address, for project 2.

Is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Each account has one billing method. The best option is likely different accounts with different payments methods set.

Organizations will consolidate billing so all accounts use the same billing method, so that won't work for you.